# How to set the width of my table in tabularray?

Tags: tables

I am very new to LaTeX, so please forgive me if my question is noobish. I am trying to make a simple table with tabularray. The main components need to be:

1. Controllable border thickness
2. Controllable borders (I want the external borders to be non-existent
3. Controllable width of the table

[image: phenomenology of tables]

Now, I've managed to figure out how to do some of the things (like border thickness and removing external borders), but I can't find the way to make the `width=0.8\linewidth` command to work. Could you please look at my code and tell me where could I possibly insert the 'width' command? Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{c|[1pt,solid]c|[1pt,solid]c} 
                   & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} \\
\hline[1pt,solid]
\textbf{text} & text               & text          \\
        
\hline[1pt,solid]
\textbf{text} & text               & text          \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{{Ideal-type of public communication in a public sphere}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Package `tabularray` has good, concise documentation. It is worth to read it.
- Documentation contain many examples, some of them are very close to what you show in question.
- In spirit of `tabularray` new syntax your example should be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{width=0.8\textwidth,
                  hline{2-Y} = 1pt, vline{2-Y} = 1pt,
                  colspec = { X[c,font=\bfseries] X[c] X[c] },
                   row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                  }
        &   text    &   text        \\
text    & text      &   text        \\
text    & text      &    text       \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{{Ideal-type of public communication in a public sphere}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I tried to read the documentation, but since I am very new to the LaTeX language, it takes some time and effort to parse through all the symbols.